# make a list using format() in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and coding in general.
Therefore I apologize if this has been talked about already and I am just unable to find it.

I am trying to get a list of stringnames.

```
for x in list:
    foldername = 'bla/exp-{number}/exp-{number}-A/bls'.format(number = x)

my_list.append(glob("/bla/bla/bla/" + foldername))
len(my_list)
```

len(my_list) returns just 2, even though x = 100

I am not really sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my_list.append is not inside the loop. Python uses *indentation as syntax*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_list.append(glob("/bla/bla/bla/" + foldername))` is called outside of the loop. So it will only append the last foldername.

Python is not my goto-language but

```
for x in list:
    foldername = 'bla/exp-{number}/exp-{number}-A/bls'.format(number = x)
    my_list.append(glob("/bla/bla/bla/" + foldername))

len(my_list)
```

Should give a diffrent result.

Answer (score 2):

You have to indent the line where you append to `mylist`:

```
for x in list:
    foldername = 'bla/exp-{number}/exp-{number}-A/bls'.format(number = x)
    my_list.append(glob("/bla/bla/bla/" + foldername))

len(my_list)
```

Comment: This will append the last foldername twice since it's still called outside of the loop as well. (Code rewritten now and no problem with it)

Comment: @dubbe yep, bad copy/paste :þ

Comment: Thankyou - by the way- why does this comment have to be longer than a certain amount of characters? I cannot just say 'thanks'. It is too short...

Comment: The idea is that you should upvote instead of saying just thanks.